# $ A * B $ computation when B is a symmetric matrix in armadillo

Tags: c++, blas, intel-mkl, armadillo

Is there any way to multiply a symmetric matrix by a dense one in armadillo(and use the fact that we have a symmetric matrix)? I know about `DSYMM` Routine in BLAS,but the matrices I'm dealing with are `mat` type(they are not arrays),So I wonder if there is some thing in armadillo using `DSYMM` Routine from BLAS .
I couldn't find any thing in armadillo documentation.

Comment: Looks like the answer is *no*.  https://gitlab.com/search?search=dsymm&project_id=6604173&search_code=true

Comment: This question is cross-posted and has been successfully answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50515957/3358223